# How to get flutter + iOS + flutter_appauth + end session to stop crashing?

Tags: ios, flutter, oauth, keycloak

Trying to use flutter_appauth and trying to get it to log out on iOS, but it seems that no matter what I've tried, it crashes.

Here's a sample of our logout code:

```
      var esr = EndSessionRequest(
          idTokenHint: idToken,
          issuer: '<ommitted from sample>',
          postLogoutRedirectUrl: 'com.myapp.myapp://login-callback',
          allowInsecureConnections: false,
          preferEphemeralSession: true,
          serviceConfiguration: <auth endpoint, token endpoint, end session...>,
      );
      await appAuth.endSession(esr);
```

Similarly, for login:

```
      final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result =
      await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        AuthorizationTokenRequest(
          <client id>,
          'com.myapp.myapp://login-callback',
          serviceConfiguration: <service config>,
          scopes: [...scopes...],
          preferEphemeralSession: true,
          allowInsecureConnections: false,
        ),
      );
```

We see this in our logs:

```
2022-09-21 10:47:16.063321-0400 Runner[59528:8189105] [Presentation] Attempt to present <SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x1064d5600> on <SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x106424800> (from <SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x106424800>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
2022-09-21 10:48:01.594067-0400 Runner[59528:8189105] No windows have a root view controller, cannot save application state
```

Under iOS/runner we have this in our plist:

```
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapp.myapp</string>
         </array>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
```

This seems to work on android just fine. Is there something else special that iOS needs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapp.myapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Explanation, dictionary keys are case sensitive, so CFBundleURLSchemes is not the same as CFBundleURLschemes. The former is the key for the array of URL schemes, the latter is the key for the URL scheme itself.